# How can I make my password function better?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I am new to React and as I am building a registration page I encountered an performance issue with my password validation function. Below is my code:

**State Defined**

```
    const [errordiv, changeViewDiv] = useState(0);
    const [passwordValid, setPasswordValid] = useState(false)
```

**Pass Check Function**

```
            changeViewDiv(1)
            // console.log(errordiv)
            const letterReg = /[a-z]/;
            const capitalReg = /[A-Z]/;
            const specialReg = /[!\@\#\$\%\^\&\(\)\_\+\-\.\,\;\:\\/]/;
            const numberReg = /[0-9]/;
            // let flag = 1;
            const input = e.target.value;
            const errorDiv = document.getElementById('message');
            // errorDiv.style.display = "block";
            Array.from(errorDiv.childNodes).slice(1, 6).forEach((item) => {
                item.children[0].style.display = "inline-block";
                item.children[1].style.display = "none"
            });
            // array.forEach((item) => {
            //     item.children[0].style.display = "inline-block";
            //     item.children[1].style.display = "none";
            // })

            if (letterReg.test(input)) {
                document.getElementById("letter").children[0].style.display = "none"
                document.getElementById("letter").children[1].style.display = "inline-block"
                // flag = 0
                setPasswordValid(true)
            }
            if (capitalReg.test(input)) {
                document.getElementById("capital").children[0].style.display = "none"
                document.getElementById("capital").children[1].style.display = "inline-block"
                // flag = 0
                setPasswordValid(true)

            }
            if (numberReg.test(input)) {
                document.getElementById("number").children[0].style.display = "none"
                document.getElementById("number").children[1].style.display = "inline-block"
                // flag = 0
                setPasswordValid(true)
            }
            if (input.length >= 8 && input.length < 16) {
                document.getElementById("length").children[0].style.display = "none"
                document.getElementById("length").children[1].style.display = "inline-block"
                // flag = 0
                setPasswordValid(true)
            }
            if (specialReg.test(input)) {
                document.getElementById("special").children[0].style.display = "none"
                document.getElementById("special").children[1].style.display = "inline-block"
                // flag = 0
                setPasswordValid(true)
            }
            // return flag
```

**Password Input Field**

```
<RStyle.Detailsform style={{ borderBottom: "initial" }} type={passInputType} id="password" name="password" minLength="8" required onInput={passCheck} onChange={inputChange} />
```

**Error Message To Display**

```
{errordiv == 1 ? <RStyle.ErrorMessage id="message">
<h4 style={{ marginBottom: "10px", fontSize: "1em" }}>Passwords must contain:</h4>
<p id="letter" className="invalid"><VscError className='errorIcon' style={errorIcon} /><VscCheck className='validIcon' style={validIcon} /> A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
<p id="capital" className="invalid"><VscError className='errorIcon' style={errorIcon} /><VscCheck className='validIcon' style={validIcon} /> A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
<p id="number" className="invalid"><VscError className='errorIcon' style={errorIcon} /><VscCheck className='validIcon' style={validIcon} /> A <b>number</b></p>
<p id="special" className="invalid"><VscError className='errorIcon' style={errorIcon} /><VscCheck className='validIcon' style={validIcon} /> A <b>special character</b></p>
<p id="length" className="invalid"><VscError className='errorIcon' style={errorIcon} /><VscCheck className='validIcon' style={validIcon} /> Length : <b>8-15</b> characters</p>
</RStyle.ErrorMessage> : null}
```

My conditions are working properly just when I press on any key for the first time the state doesn't change immediately and pressing the key again it starts working. How can I fix this issue?

I have attached the screenshot of the error console

[Error appearing in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFg2p.png)

Comment: Enforcing character set requirements in password is generally... a bad idea and horrible UI/UX.

Comment: @Terry May I know which approach I can use other than character set requirements?

Comment: Just don't enforce any requirements, perhaps a minimum length is enough...

Answer (score 0):

Those error messages are rendered conditionally which will make you validate stuff and try to access the DOM in search of elements that will only be synchronously be renderer after the check function.
Your access to **e.g.:** `document.getElementById("number").children[1].style.display`is undefined.

Edit (Proposal for errors):

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
```

```
<div className="errors">
  {errors.map(error => <p>{error}</p>)}
</div>
```

Instead of setting display you just push errors to array using setState:

```
setErrors(previousState => [...previousState].push(error))
```

Comment: So is there any better approach to handle it? @RicardoFerreira

Comment: You could have only 1 div(parent container) and simply map errors array to a set of p tags with your styling.

Comment: I didn't quite get you...can you share some sample code? 

Comment: All you need to do when you find an error is push errors to an array.
That array will then be reflected on jsx code with a mapping of the errors to your p tags.
Instead of changing children.style you just push errors to array. After that with the errors.map, you'll be left with the errors displayed on screen.